# Natural sounding speech synthesis for generating short words such as logatomes

Tags: speech-synthesis

I want to evaluate if modern speech synthesis can be used in an audiometric context. My idea is to generate short words and use this in an experimental study where I compare the outcomes of a synthetic speech test and an existing speech test (based on voice acting). Which tools would you recommend for this type of speech synthesis?

Requested features:

- Voice quality that is close to a natural sounding voice when generating single syllable words
- Possibility to generate new voices with relative ease
- Possibility to modulate prosodic features
- Language support is of secondary importance since I might use it to generate nonsense words (logatomes) but support for swedish would be nice

The output of TensorFlow WaveNet seems to be unpredictable gibberish so I don't think that's an option. I have looked into Festival a bit but judging by the samples it doesn't really sound natural enough. But maybe the samples doesn't make it justice?

Comment: Such thing does not exist yet

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev What about TensorFlow Tacotron? The samples sounds a bit too unnatural but still promising. Maybe it would be ok with more training than what they have used?

Comment: Wavenet has very hard time to create new voices for example, so many of your requirements are not easy to satisfy.